# Место хранения триггера

Tags: sql-server

Создал триггер типа `instead of insert`, отладил его, все прекрасно работает, но вот незадача: когда я закрыл `sql server (2008)`, а потом опять захотел потестить этот триггер, я его не нашел. Вызвать я его могу и все правильно отрабатывает (то есть где-то он хранится точно), но я никак не могу найти где именно. Искал в папках: триггеров базы, хранимых процедурах, функциях, представлениях, везде, наверное, где можно. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Триггер просто был привязан к конкретной таблице , в папке triggers.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from syscomments 
join sysobjects on syscomments.id=sysobjects.id where sysobjects.xtype='TR'
```

Comment: @DeVinchi, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.